# Getting KeyError at /vaccine 'sessions' in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Hi I making a page where user can enter pincode for their respective state and can get availability of vaccine in their area.
But I am getting KeyError at /vaccine 'sessions' in django
But I remove the pincode option from views and put a specific code i.e, pincodeU = '110046' then it will work.

**my views.py**

```
def vaccine(request):
    today = date.today()
    d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
    pincodeU = str(pincode)
    # if I remove above two line and put pincodeU = '110046' then it will work
    baseurl = 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?pincode={}&date={}'.format(pincodeU,d1)
    
    vaccine = requests.get(baseurl)
    data = vaccine.json()
    vaccinedata = data["sessions"]
    return render(request, 'vaccine_data.html', {'vaccinedata':vaccinedata})90
```

**vaccine_data.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock title %} {% block body %}

<div class="form-control">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="pincode">Enter Pincode</label>
        <input type="text" name="pincode">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Center ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Fee Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Vaccine</th>
                <th scope="col">Age limit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {% for i in vaccinedata %}

            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                <td>{{i.center_id}}</td>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.address}}</td>
                <td>{{i.fee_type}}</td>
                <td>{{i.vaccine}}</td>
                <td>{{i.min_age_limit}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> {% endblock body %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from home import views
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = [
  path('',views.index, name="home"),
  path('home',views.index, name="home"),
  path('vaccine',views.vaccine, name="vaccine"),
]
```

Comment: try to `print(data)` and check that you are getting session or not

Comment: yes I am getting the data

Comment: I think I need to put some initial value in pincode since when I run it with an static pincode rather than getting it from user then it work fine.

Comment: basically we get `KeyError` when we try to access key from dict which is not exists so in your case maybe you are not getting `sessions` key

Comment: you can use try except to handle this error and return error to user that `sessions` does not exists in your area

Comment: check 6th line of views.py, it will perfectly if I do that.

Comment: yes i know but it will get static pin code which is provided by you not from user

Comment: Hey you din't put any form action

Comment: add action to your form than it will work

Comment: Not working.. after adding action.

Comment: Done Bro Thanks Try Except Worked..